go - docker build fails confluent kafka
I have this docker file, but I'm having problems building it due to the Kafka Confluent lib, does anyone know how I can solve it?
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential pkg-config git gcc libc-dev librdkafka-dev -y 

DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV CGO_ENABLED 1
RUN useradd --create-home --uid 1000 go
WORKDIR /home
USER 1000

COPY bin .

CMD ["./api"]

basically errors in all uses of the libs:
undefined: kafka.Consumer
kafkajob/queue.go:219:26: too many errors

and anothers structs

What system is building the api binary? Maybe you should use multi stage build with a golang container then copy to ubuntu image?

Would you give me a code of ./api? I want to reproduce the problem in my machine.
